# issue in installation of mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I was in stalling mongo DB on my UBUNTU-12.04 system,but while i give the following command in my terminal

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
```

It gives me the following error

```
gpg: requesting key 7F0CEB10 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

Is there any other way of installing mongo db or what can be done to avoid the above situation

Thanks

Comment: You might have more luck on our sister site http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

This looks to have been a temporary Ubuntu keyserver issue, as

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
```

works for me.